# Programmatically show parent and child categories on frontend

Tags: category, frontend, store-view, static-block

Currently these are being rendered with cms blocks. Is there a way to include this type of functionality in a template which gets categories and subcategories and displays them like so:

[image: example image]

We just want to ensure that if links change or categories change in the admin panel that the links on the frontend will adjust automatically. What's the most efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: This would be really useful to know, thanks for asking as we've just used static blocks before, but when you get into multistores this becomes a real headache.

Answer (score 2):

simple way is to add a phtml file, which uses the following collection:

```
$categories = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('name')
->addIsActiveFilter()
->addFieldToFilter('level', array('gt' => '1'));
```

and a foreach loop

```
foreach ($categories as $category):
...
your html
...
endforach;
```

and call that phtml file in your cms page / static block.

**EDIT:**

More reference:

[add categories with images on homepage – magento](http://samsami2u.wordpress.com/2009/09/15/add-categories-with-images-on-homepage-magento/)

[category tree in magento with more level on the frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12058143/category-tree-in-magento-with-more-level-on-the-frontend)

[Magento - get a parent category and all sub-sub-categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564647/magento-get-a-parent-category-and-all-sub-sub-categories)

The effiient way would be, to create a module with just Block and Helper classes

1. phtml instance to be instantiated in Block.
2. Helper class to contain a method/function to fetch the children categories of the given category id.
3. This method can be called recursively in phtml file to display all the categories and their sub categories.

> for example:
>
> ```
> $children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(_CATEGORY_ID_)->getChildrenCategories();
>             foreach($children as $child){
>                 echo $child->getName() . " " . $child->getUrl() . "<br/>";
>             }
> ```

Comment: You might want to change the level filter to `->addFieldToFilter('level', array('gt' => '1'));`. Level 0 is for "root of roots" and level 1 is for the root categories. You want to exclude them.

Comment: done editing, I thing they wanna show the root categories as well.

Comment: Root categories are usually not shown anywhere. They are used for setting the category tree to a website. a root category is 'Root Category' in the backend.

Comment: I'm bit confused now, does that mean "Root Catalog" is level 1? I thought it was level 0!

Comment: Yep. Check the table `catalog_category_entity`. There is an entry there that is not visible in the frontend with ID 1 and level 0. That's a "root of roots" and all catalog roots are children of that "hidden" category. You can also check in a custom script by doing this: `$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(ROOT_ID_HERE); var_dump($category->getLevel())`. You should get `1`.

Comment: ah! 15 months I didn't know this! Thank you Marius.

Comment: You're welcome. and don't worry. I think it took me more than that to find out :)

Comment: So in my Rails experience, I would create a partial that would simply retrieve the desired data and iterate through it and then include it in the main template.  I'd be interested in seeing this fleshed out more specifically implementation wise as it seems like a valuable example of doing this "right" in magento vs some of the ways I've seen it done strictly in the CMS.

Comment: check here  http://magentocodes.blogspot.in/2015/10/how-to-get-category-tree-structure-in.html